# Check if a button is triggered by clicking enter key using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

How to check if a button element is triggered by clicking enter using selenium? For example I'm testing the following table which has buttons in it

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>col1</th>
            <th>col2</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">row1</th>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">action 1</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-secondary">action 2</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">row2</th>
            <td><button class="btn hover btn-primary">action 1</button></td>
            <td><button class="btn hover btn-secondary">action 2</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to know if these buttons are triggered on clicking enter.

Comment: Normally the element itself or it's wrapper or some other element will change some class attribute like `active`. Can you share a link to the page you working on?

Comment: Maybe a `print('clicked the button')` - after the actual `send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`, successfully displayed in terminal or returned somewhere, would confirm the previous action was performed without errors.